# Why supposing that $\operatorname{char}(F) \neq 2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, bilinear-form, positive-characteristic

I have a question regarding to part$(b)$ in the problem below:

"
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F,$ and let $B$ be a bilinear form on V.

$(b)$ Suppose $\operatorname{char}(F) \neq 2.$ $B$ is said to be skew-symmetric if $B(v_1, v_2) = -B(v_2, v_1)$ for all $v_1, v_2 \in V.$ Prove that if $B$ is skew-symmetric then its matrix (with respect to any basis) is skew-symmetric."

Why the author is excluding the field of characteristic $2$? could anyone answer this question to me please?

Comment: Sorry yes you are right that the $char(F)\ne 2$ assumption is not useful, in the $e_j$ basis the matrix is $M_{ij}=B(e_i,e_j)=-B(e_j,e_i)=-M_{ji}$, so it is skew symmetric, which in characteristic $2$ is the same as symmetric.

Comment: you should know that there is another definition of skew symmetry, namely $B(v,v)= 0$ for all $v\in V$.  This is implied by your definition for $\text{char }\mathbb F \neq 2$ but it also works quite well in characteristic 2 unlike your definition.  Skew symmetry is frequently easier to work with than symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the characteristic is 2, then $-1=1$ and signs make no sense. It is not reasonable to talk about skew-symmetricity in that case.